# Inserting elements to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `Cb`. I want to insert element 0 at `len(Cb[0])` but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
Cb=[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]] 

for i in range(0,len(Cb[0])):
    Cb=Cb[0].insert(0,len(Cb[0])) 
print(Cb)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Cb=Cb[0].insert(0,len(Cb[0]))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output is

```
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: why not `Cb[0].append(0)` ?...

Comment: When I use ```Cb.append([0])```, I get ```[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0]]``` and the expected output is ```[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]```.

Comment: so do `Cb[0].append(0)`

Comment: If you want to append elements to the first element in `Cb`, don't append elements to `Cb`. Instead: `Cb[0].append(0)`.

Comment: If you just want to insert one new element, I don't understand why you are looping and calling the method `insert` 3 times.

Comment: Use `Cb[0].insert(len(Cb[0]),0.0) ` without the loop and without assigning to Cb. Note the arguments to insert are the other way round.

Comment: The `list.insert()` method destructively modifies the list, and returns `None`.  So `Cb=Cb[0].insert(0,len(Cb[0]))` modifies the list referenced by `Cb`, then sets `Cb` to `None`.  After that you have no way to access the list.  Get rid of the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append to the inner list using `Cb[0].append(0)`

Answer (score 1):

`list.insert()` returns None thats why you're getting an error try this :

```
Cb = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

Cb[0].extend([0] * (len(Cb[0]) + 1 - len(Cb[0])))

print(Cb)
```

Here's a version of code that is more dynamic and return the expected ouptup

Answer (score 1):

```
cb=[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
cb[0].append(0.0)
print(cb)
```

Output is :

```
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```